# Выгрузить метки из MySql и добавить на карту через html форму

Tags: mysql, yandex-maps-api

Есть база данных СТО и форма html, в которую пользователь вводит марку и должны выгружаться СТО работающие с этой маркой машины.
У меня получается сформировать json и выгрузить в том случае, если я сам ввожу SQL запрос, то есть он статичен, но надо чтоб данные посылались с html формы и выводились найденные.

Файл формирования json:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymapapiv2_markers WHERE id = '4'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
while ($mar = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$json =  array(icontext=>$mar['iconText'], hinttext=>$mar['hintText'], balloontext=>$mar['balloonText'], styleplacemark=>$mar['stylePlacemark'], lat=>$mar['lat'], lon=>$mar['lon']);
$markers[] = $json;
}
}
$points = array(markers=>$markers);
echo json_encode($points);
<?
```

сама форма:

```
<form name="" action="vivodpointsmap.php" method="get">
    <div class="form-grp">
    <input class="select-menu" name="mark" type="text">
    </div>
    <input class="select-menu" type="submit" value="search" name="search" id="submit">
</form>
```

я понимаю, почему они не выводится, так-как в обработчике формы нет вывода карты, но если я туда что-либо добавляю, то он не работает.

выгрузка карты:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

        //Определение начальных параметров карты
        function init () {
            var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: [55.035130661714284, 82.89889020518926], 
                    zoom: 10
                }, {
                    balloonMaxWidth: 600
                });

            //Добавляем элементы управления 
            myMap.controls                
                .add('zoomControl')                
                .add('typeSelector')                
                .add('mapTools');

            //Запрос данных и вывод маркеров на карту
        $.getJSON("vivodpointsmap.php",
        function(json){
                for (i = 0; i < json.markers.length; i++) {

                    var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([json.markers[i].lat,json.markers[i].lon], {
                    // Свойства
                    iconContent: json.markers[i].icontext, 
                    hintContent: json.markers[i].hinttext,
                    balloonContentBody: json.markers[i].balloontext                   
                    }, {
                    // Опции
                    preset: json.markers[i].styleplacemark                  
                });

                // Добавляем метку на карту
                myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);

            }

        }); 
        }
```

Comment: Чтобы заменить WHERE id = '4' на переменную mark из формы - вам нужно (см. [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php))  использовать переменную $_GET['mark'] -- при этом вас код будет небезопастным с точки зрения sql-инъекций (см. например [тут](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/393450/)) и мне кажется, что вам непросто будет справится с переходом к более безопасному коду (много придётся переписать, много освоить). Но хотя бы используйте приведение к (int)

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, но карта не выводится, так-как запрос в action обрабатывает файл, где нельзя карту вывести, иначе файл в виде json не будет работать. Подскажите пожалуйста как одновременно послать переменную для обработки и вывести карту?

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить, что вы перепутали `Lat` и `Lng` (`Lon`). В яндекс-картах, в отличие от гугловских, сначала идет широта, потом долгота.

Comment: В начале да,вы правы,я их перепутал, но я уже это исправил) дело в том, что они все нормально выводятся на карту, но я не могу указывать по какому критерию брать из базы.

Comment: Я поставил к примеру -"WHERE id = '4', но надо чтоб тут стояла переманная,допусти $mark, которая присылается из формы.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил сделать так:

```
<form name="get_form" action="vivodpointsmap.php">
    <div class="form-grp">
    <input class="select-menu" name="mark" type="text">
    </div>
    <input class="select-menu" type="submit" value="search" name="search" id="submit">
</form>
```

внутри функии init() добавить:

```
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
        clusterize: true,
        // ObjectManager принимает те же опции, что и кластеризатор.
        gridSize: 32,
        useMapMargin: false,
        clusterIconLayout: "default#pieChart",
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
        // Если Мы хотим загружать данные для балуна перед открытием, то
        // запретим автоматически открывать балун по клику.
        //geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick: false,
        balloonContentLayoutWidth: 250,
    });
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $('#submit').click(function (e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        ajax_get();

   // Если в properties будут добавлены еще какие-нибудь поля, 
    // то в последствии можно фильтровать по ним (тут например добавлен "type":
    //  objectManager.setFilter( function(object) {    
    //      return object.properties.type == 1;
    //  });
    });
    ajax_get = function(){
        var form_value  = $("form[name=get_form]").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'vivodpointsmap.php?mode=get',
            type: 'POST',
            data: form_value,
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
                //
            },
            success: function(res) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON( res );
                objectManager.add(data);
                myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
            },
            error: function(response) {
                alert('Ошибка cервера:'+response);
            }         
        });
    }
```

ну и собственно PHP скрипт (vivodpointsmap.php), который будет принимать запрос и отдавать JSON результат:

```
if($mode == 'get')
{
    $id = (isset($_GET['mark'])) ? intval($_GET['mark']) : intval($_POST['mark']);
    //тут можно сделать еще проверку от инъекций или использовать готовые ф-ции
    //
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymapapiv2_markers WHERE id = ".$id);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $json =  array(
                'type'  => "Feature",
                'id'    => $row['id'],
                'geometry' => array(
                        'type' => "Point",
                        'coordinates' => array( $row['lat'],$row['lon'] )
                    ),
                'properties' => array(
                        'balloonContent' => $row['balloonText'],
                        'clusterCaption' => $row['iconText'], 
                        'hintContent' => $row['hintText'], 
                        'iconContent' => $row['iconText'],
                    ), 
                'options' => array(
                        'iconColor' => "#ff0000", 
                        'preset' => "islands#blueCircleDotIcon",
                        'hideIconOnBalloonOpen' => false,
                        //'balloonPanelMapMaxArea' => "Infinity",
                        //'draggable' => true
                    ),
            );

            $markers[] = $json;
        }

        $json_arr = array(type=>"FeatureCollection", features=>$markers);       
    }
    echo json_encode($json_arr);
}
```

Comment: для получения POST - GET я лично пользуюсь готовой ф-цией, взятой из движка PHPBB. Если нужна, могу скинуть ))))
вызов там осуществляется так:  

request_var ( $var_name , $default [, $multibyte [, $cookie ]] ) 

т.е. в данном случае будет получение нужного параметра выглядеть так: $id = request_var('mark', 0); второй аргумент - значение по умолчанию, и указывает что надо проверить, что значение - число а не строка.